# Postman - Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

Tags: django, rest, post, postman, csrf-token

Ive been having problems getting started with postman - I've used it before with Spring but its my first time with Django.

I have a working website with all URLs working well. When I send a post request in postman to a page that has a csrftoken, I can see the token in the cookies section of the results, but I get the following error in the server output:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /contact/
```

I have the token in the [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tQ2G.png) section

I have tried quite a few different solutions from stack overflow such as adding:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ...
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False#I am over the localhost with http

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
```

This is what the view looks like

```
def contact(request):
"""Renders the contact page."""
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm()
else:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        ... sending email ...

        return redirect('contact')
    return HttpResponse(status=303)
return render(
    request,
    'app/contact.html',
    {
        'title':'Contact Us',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
        'form': form,
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the csrf token in html by having this in the django jinja template

```
{{csrf_token}}
```

Render the page and you have that value.
Then use the value as part of your POST request's data:

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : <csrf_token_value>
```

Comment: thanks - i had the token in the template, do i need to put 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : <csrf_token_value> in the Body of the postman request? (in form-data format?) i gave it a try but i couldn't get it to work